# Pydantic model fields with typing.Optional[] vs. typing.Optional[] = None

Tags: python, annotations, python-typing, pydantic

What is the distinction between implicitly setting an optional attribute to None with `typing.Optional[]` versus explicitly assigning `typing.Optional[] = None` when creating *Pydantic* models? In both cases, the attribute will eventually have a value of `None` when the class object is instantiated.

```py
import typing
import pydantic


class Bar(pydantic.BaseModel):
    a: typing.Optional[int]

    @pydantic.validator('a', always=True, pre=True)
    def check_a(cls, v, values, field):
        print("WITHOUT NONE")
        print(values)
        print(field)
        return v


class Baz(pydantic.BaseModel):
    a: typing.Optional[int] = None

    @pydantic.validator('a', always=True, pre=True)
    def check_a(cls, v, values, field):
        print("WITH NONE")
        print(values)
        print(field)
        return v


print(Bar())
print(Baz())
```

Output:

```
WITHOUT NONE
{}
name='a' type=Optional[int] required=False default=None
a=None
WITH NONE
{}
name='a' type=Optional[int] required=False default=None
a=None
```

Comment: If you don't give it an initial value, you'll get an error if you try to use the variable before assigning it.

Comment: @Barmar This is the case with _all other_ types. But not with unions with `None`. It is a deliberate inconsistency in Pydantic. `Optional[T]` fields implicitly always have the `None` default value (unless another is specified.

Comment: https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/migration/#required-optional-and-nullable-fields

Answer (score 10):

#### Attention, this  only holds for v1. For v2, check the answer by @elachere.

## TL;DR

There is no difference. At least in terms of functionality. One *implicitly* sets the default value as `None` (unless another default is specified). The other *explicitly* sets the default as `None`.

---

## Details

### A deliberate (?) inconsistency

You may already know that [`Optional[T]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) is equivalent to `Union[T, None]` or `T | None` (in the newer notation). In **all other cases** with types `T` and `U` simply annotating a field as `a: T | U` and *not* providing an explicit default value would make that a [**required** field](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#required-fields). In the Pydantic lingo that means you cannot instantiate the model without (somehow) providing a value for that field and that value will have to be either of type `T` or of type `U` to pass validation.

The union `T | None` is an exception to this rule that is (arguably) not obvious, so you might call it an inconsistency. But it seems to be intentional. Annotating a field with such a union (so for example `a: Optional[T]`) will always create a field that is **not required** and has the default value `None` (unless of course you specify some other default).

### Implementation details

Under the hood, this happens during model creation after a `ModelField` instance has been all but created and its [`prepare`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.9/pydantic/fields.py#L539) method is called. It calls the [`_type_analysis`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.9/pydantic/fields.py#L583) method to determine more details about the field type. And after [recognizing the type origin to be a **union**](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.9/pydantic/fields.py#L644), its type arguments are looked at in turn and once one of them is [determined to be the `NoneType`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.9/pydantic/fields.py#L647), the field's `required` attribute is set to `False` and its `allow_none` attribute to `True`. Then, a bit later because the field still [has an undefined `default` attribute](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.9/pydantic/fields.py#L555), that attribute is set to `None`. That last step is obviously skipped, if you *explicitly* define a default value (`None` or some instance of `T`) or a default factory.

### Runtime implications

In practice this means that for the following model **all** fields behave identically in the sense that

1. **neither** is required during initialization because
2. **all** of them will receive `None` as their value, when no other value is provided,
3. and the type of **each** of them is set to be `Optional[str]`.

```py
from typing import Optional, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Model(BaseModel):
    a: str | None
    b: Union[str, None]
    c: Optional[str]
    d: Optional[str] = None
    e: Optional[str] = Field(default=None)
    f: Optional[str] = Field(default_factory=lambda: None)
    g: str = None


obj = Model()
print(obj.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "a": null,
    "b": null,
    "c": null,
    "d": null,
    "e": null,
    "f": null,
    "g": null
}
```

Note that even `g` is implicitly handled in a way that sets its type to be `Optional[str]`, even though we annotate it with just `str`. You can verify this by doing the following:

```py
for field in Model.__fields__.values():
    print(repr(field))
```

Output:

```
ModelField(name='a', type=Optional[str], required=False, default=None)
ModelField(name='b', type=Optional[str], required=False, default=None)
ModelField(name='c', type=Optional[str], required=False, default=None)
ModelField(name='d', type=Optional[str], required=False, default=None)
ModelField(name='e', type=Optional[str], required=False, default=None)
ModelField(name='f', type=Optional[str], required=False, default_factory='<function <lambda>>')
ModelField(name='g', type=Optional[str], required=False, default=None)
```

By the way, you *can* also make a field of the type `Optional[T]` **and** required. To do that you simply have to set the default to the ellipsis `...`, so `field: Optional[str] = ...` for example would make that field accept `None` as a value, but still **require** you to provide a value during initialization. (see [docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#required-optional-fields))

### Clean code considerations

This is more subjective of course, but I would suggest adhering to the [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Especially since this behavior is so inconsistent and not obvious unless you are already familiar with Pydantic, you should **not omit** the default value even though you can. It just takes you a few more characters to add  `= None` to the field definition, but it is much clearer for you later on or some other person reading the code.

I would also **not** recommend **omitting** the `NoneType` from the annotation. The reason is the same. Field `g` from the previous example might work just fine, but it undergoes an *implicit* change of its type.

My recommendation is to do `field: Optional[str] = None`, if you are dealing with just one additional type and `field: str | int | None`, if there are more types (or the older `Union` notation, if you are on Python `<=3.9`).

Answer (score 7):

Whilst the previous answer is correct for pydantic v1, note that [pydantic v2](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/releases/tag/v2.0), released 2023-06-30, changed this behavior.

As specified in the [migration guide](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/migration/#required-optional-and-nullable-fields):

> Pydantic V2 changes some of the logic for specifying whether a field annotated as Optional is required (i.e., has no default value) or not (i.e., has a default value of None or any other value of the corresponding type), and now more closely matches the behavior of dataclasses. Similarly, fields annotated as Any no longer have a default value of None.