# Pydantic 2.0 ignores Optional in schema and requires the field to be available

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

Pydantic 2.0 seems to have drastically changed.

Previously with FastAPI and Pydantic 1.X I could define the schema like this, where receipt is optional:

```
class VerifyReceiptIn(BaseModel):
    device_id: str
    device_type: DeviceType
    receipt: Optional[str]
```

Then in FastAPI endpoint I could do this:

```
@router_verify_receipt.post(
    "/",
    status_code=201,
    response_model=VerifyReceiptOut,
    responses={201: {"model": VerifyReceiptOut}, 400: {"model": HTTPError}},
)
async def verify_receipt(body: VerifyReceiptIn):
    auth_service = AuthService()
    ...
```

And the unit test without receipt in body was fine with it, but now with Pydantic 2.0 it's failing. Now it claims that Receipt is required and throws a 422 error.

```
response = await client.post(
            "/verify-receipt/",
            headers={"api-token": "abc123"},
            json={
                "device_id": "u1",
                "device_type": DeviceType.ANDROID.value,
            },
        )
```

But this is why we had Optional. Why do I have to pass `receipt=None` in body? This is not ideal as it will break everything on production. Is there a way around this? Thanks

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76467243/19770795) may be of interest to you for understanding, what was going in Pydantic v1. The fact that you could omit values for `Optional[T]` fields even though you never explicitly defined a **default** for them was inconsistent behavior. I for one am very glad they [decided](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/6475#issuecomment-1623230665) to change this in v2 and force people to explicitly define defaults. If you want `receipt` to default to `None` then specify that in the model: `receipt: Optional[str] = None`

Comment: In addition to @DaniilFajnberg's comment above, you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289969/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804) helpful as well.

Comment: Ah Thanks guys. I understand now. Maybe you would like to add an answer with `receipt: Optional[str] = None` and I accept. I just tested it and it works. In the hindsight it was obvious, but didn't understand it yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed Pydantic v2 changed the behavior of `Optional` to a more strict and correct one. The [Pydantic 2.0 Migration Guide](https://docs.pydantic.dev/dev-v2/migration/#required-optional-and-nullable-fields) has a special section describing the new behavior.

According to the Guide `Optional[str]` is now treated as required but allowed to have `None` as its value. See the example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Model(BaseModel):
    value: Optional[str]

m = Model(value='abc')  # passes
m = Model(value=None)  # passes
m = Model()  # fails
```

Think of `Optional[str]` as of `str | None`. And in general `A | B` requires the value to be of type `A` or `B`.

For the value to be not required it has to have a default value like in the following example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Model(BaseModel):
    value: str | None = 'nothing'

m = Model(value='abc')  # passes
m = Model(value=None)  # passes
m = Model()  # passes and sets `value` to `'nothing'`
```

If you'd change `value: str | None = 'nothing'` to `value: str | None = None` you'll get a value that is not required and has a default value `None`.